# Android : call httpget with redirect_uri

Tags: android, facebook, redirect, uri

I want to make httpget request by android application,

```
 URL = https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<number>&redirect_uri=<SOME_URL>&scope=email
```

Above URL is working fine with browser, It give me proper result on server side, but when I am making http call from application it won't work, got the 200 Response, but it won't give me result.

Code snippet:

```
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    httpParams.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,                        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                            CONN_TIMEOUT);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    Log.d(TAG,"URL :"+ httpGet.getURI().toURL().toString());            
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);            

    //Log.d(TAG,"httpResponse :" +EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
    res = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    Log.d(TAG, "Response : " + res);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because

```
200 response code "OK"
The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response is dependent on the method used in the request,if there is some result request code will 204
```

Comment: @Nimit you need to check your url might not be right which only use for post not for get may be